# Rspec stubbing return values from a given block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to get to grips with stubbing in Rspec. I would like to understand how to stub returns values from an array.

Here is what I am attempting to stub at the moment,

```
if client.jobs.any?
      client.jobs.map do |job|
        if job.job_locations.any?
            job.job_locations.map do |jl| 
                if jl.location_id == self.location_id
                    errors.add(:location_id, "This location is in use with another of the client's jobs")
                    return false
                end
            end
        end
      end
    end
```

I can stub the first line (that there the client has jobs) but I am not sure how to stub the return values of the array so that they run in the spec tests.

here is the relevant snippet

```
        context "location_id matches job_location location_id" do 
          before do
            allow(client_location).to receive(:client).and_return(client)
            allow(client).to receive(:jobs).and_return(some_jobs) 
            allow(some_jobs).to receive(:map).and_return([job]) 
            #eventually I want to get to this
            allow_any_instance_of(JobLocation).to receive(:location_id).and_return(1)
            allow_any_instance_of(ClientLocation).to receive(:location_id).and_return(1)
          end
          it "returns false" do 
            expect(@instance.destroy).to be_falsey
          end
        end
```

I should add the 'some_jobs' variables in the spec test are factory girl generated instances. Some jobs would equal [some_jobs].

Comment: OMG! Your code is waiting for a refactoring..Really :-)

Comment: yes exactly - i write the tests first, then i refactor!

Comment: @Anthony ... I know what you meant.. lol ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you define `some_jobs` to be `[job]` (e.g. via RSpec's `let` mechanism), then you don't need to redefine map and your production code will continue to execute. By stubbing out `some_jobs.map`, you basically bypassed the rest of your production code.

As an aside, the definitions of `client_location`, `client`, `some_jobs` and `job` are all highly relevant to the code snippet you shared and should be included.